# Spring MVC model for multiple forms

Tags: spring-mvc

I have model called User, which is also an entity. I use it in multiple forms, however sometimes I'd like to put there some values that my model doesn't have. For example I've got model User with fields username, password, email. Now I'd like to pass value of field that my model doesn't contains, e.g. rememberMe. I don't know how to solve this,  for me there are 2 options:

A) I extended the model/entity with field rememberMe annotated as @Transient so it doesn't put useless information to my DB

B) I create another model class with field rememberMe and so on - new model for every page that requires it.

Comment: Edit rolled back. C'mon, editors: You can't accept an edit that introduces typos and just adds a few quotes around things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I often implement your choice A). It is easy and fast, but break a little bit the separation of concern.

For B) choice you can make a UserForm class that extends the User class with rememberMe property.

Comment: It depends what you consider a right way, for my boss time is money. And I find A) is not that dirty and ultra quick, so I think it is the right way. Maybe if you have more complex Form object with severals @Transient it can be worth it to go B).

Comment: OK last question from me I guess: will it matter, if my class have 20, 50, 100 fields?